# How to segregate AWS Lambda functions per service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We're experimenting with moving over some of our services to AWS lambda. Each service has 5-10 lambda functions. The total invocation count is around 1500 per second.

Recently we had an issue where a bug in one service caused the lambda to slow down. This resulted in that all the lambda functions in all services got throttled to a point where our circuit breakers mapped the services out. This bug should only have affected one service, but now instead all services running on lambda got affected.

Is it possible to segregate the lambda functions to run in different "resource groups"?